# Should I update OpenSSL?

Tags: centos, openssl

Since the problems with version 0.9.8 of OpenSSL, I have some queries. I am told that I do not have a vulnerable version, but I want to know what your recommendations are. Should I update to a more recent version? Should I apply a patch? And why? Would an update to OpenSSL affect Apache and PHP?

My current version of OpenSSL is 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 5 updates continue through Mar 31, 2017.

Unless some special case applies, the best (and easiest!) general policy is to apply all updates your distro releases. So if CentOS updates OpenSSL, you should. If they don't, you don't need to.

Special cases would be things like you absolutely need a newer version because an app you're running needs features in it. Special cases to not update would be that you tested an update and it broke something you depend on, and you can otherwise mitigate the security concerns the update addressed. (Also, please report the bug.)

Answer (score 0):

Besides "the problems" in 0.9.8, there are always further minor/major fixes in each version. So my recommendation is: yes, update. Apache and PHP shouldn't be affected [citation needed].